# Can't find target when searching array in c

Tags: c, arrays, struct, target

I have a function here that finds the first occurrance of the "target" of an array, starting from index 0 and if it's found, set *i to that value.  When I ran the code, I tried using target = 127, and the array being [20, 127, 30, 4].  127 is in the array, but my test program said that the target couldn't be found in the array.  Would anybody know why my program fails to find the target even though I already have ia->data[x] == target?

Here is my struct that I created:

```
typedef struct {
  int* data;
  unsigned int len;
} intarr_t;
```

And this is the code for my search for the target function:

```
intarr_result_t intarr_find( intarr_t* ia, int target, int* i )
{
    unsigned int len = ia->len;
    if (ia == NULL)
    {
        return INTARR_BADARRAY;
    }
    else
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < len; x++)
        {
            if ((ia->data[x] == target) && (i != NULL))
            {
                *i = x;
                return INTARR_OK;
            }
            else
            {
                return INTARR_NOTFOUND;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because you have not searched the whole array - you return at the first element no matter what... and BTW you should check for `(ia == NULL)` *before* `len = ia->len;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code reports that the element was not found if the *first* element in the array is not the one you're looking for -- it runs into the else branch during the first loop pass and returns `INTARR_NOTFOUND` from the function.

Instead, you have to check all elements and only report that nothing has been found after the loop has ended unsuccessfully. For example:

```
intarr_result_t intarr_find( intarr_t* ia, int target, int* i )
{
  if (ia == NULL)
  {
    return INTARR_BADARRAY;
  }
  else
  {
    for (int x = 0; x < ia->len; x++)
    {
      // Condition here also fixed: Before, if i was NULL,
      // nothing would ever be found.
      if (ia->data[x] == target)
      {
        if(i != NULL) {
          *i = x;
        }

        return INTARR_OK;
      }
    }
  }

  return INTARR_NOTFOUND;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not searched the whole array - you return at the first element no matter what.

```
intarr_result_t intarr_find( intarr_t* ia, int target, int* i )
{
    if (ia == NULL || i == NULL)
        return INTARR_BADARRAY;
    for (int x = 0; x < ia->len; x++)
    {
        if (ia->data[x] == target)
        {
            *i = x;
            return INTARR_OK;
        }
    }
    return INTARR_NOTFOUND;
}
```